# Entity Framework async insert if not exist

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous

I am trying to implement Entity Framework add object if it doesn't exist already. I need to do the function async.

Here is what I wrote, but it doesn't work (no exception but doesn't work - it doesn't insert the object into the database):

```
public async Task<Manufacturer> InsertNewManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer)
{
        Manufacturer m = await db.Manufacturers.Where(ma => ma.Name == manufacturer.Name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (m != null)
        {
            return m;
        }
        else
        {
            db.Manufacturers.Add(manufacturer);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return manufacturer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way -

```
public async Task<Manufacturer> InsertNewManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer)
    {
        return await insert(manufacturer);
    }

    private async Task<Manufacturer> insert(Manufacturer m)
    {
        Task<int> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return db.Manufacturers.Count(ma => ma.Name == m.Name);
        });
        Task.WaitAll(t);
        if (t.Result == 0)
        {
            db.Manufacturers.Add(m);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
        return m;
    }
```

does it works async?